# MongoDB map/reduce "NoMethodError: undefined method `map_reduce' for #<Moped::Collection"

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to use map_reduce on a collection, via the ruby console , but I am getting "NoMethodError: undefined method `map_reduce' for #

```
results = Thing.collection.map_reduce(map, reduce, out: "vr")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Map Reduce in Mongoid 3 works slightly differently. The syntax you have would work for the mongo ruby driver.  In Mongoid 3, you call this off the class or criteria, like the following:

From a criteria:

```
Model.where(field: value).map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true)
```

From a class:

```
SomeClass.map_reduce(map, reduce).out(replace: "mr-results").each do |document|
  #do something
end
```

You can find more information on this in the [Mongoid docs](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html#map_reduce)

Comment: Not sure if your answer applies. Here is what I am following http://www.packtpub.com/article/ruby-mongodb-web-developement

Comment: The example you have given is using Mongoid 2.2.1, whereas the error you are receiving refers to `Moped::Collection`. Moped is the MongoDB driver for  Mongoid 3.  In Mongoid 2, you would pass the map reduce to the Ruby Driver in the format you have given.  In Mongoid 3, map/reduce is called from a class or criteria - not from a collection.